# Jasmine testcase : How to resolve locale.ready()

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am working on AngularJs 1.5 and just started off with Jasmine and Karma for testcases...
My controllers make use of

```
locale.ready('common').then(function () {
})
```

I am not able to mock 'locale'. Though its should have been straightforward as for other services.
I found something on the internet for this purpose, but the documentation does not have a working code:

> 'karma-json-preprocessor'

Can I get a sample code that demonstrates how to mock locale in this scenario?

EDIT: (29May'17)
Below is the sample code:
promise returns the object containing the localization keys & values:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('mytestcontroller', ['$scope', 'locale',
        function ($scope, locale) {
            locale.ready('common').then(function (res) {
                $scope.reportname = 'gauravreport';
            });
        }
    ]);
```

Below is a sample code I am trying:

```
var scope, controller;
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, locale) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('mytestcontroller', {
            '$scope': scope,
            'locale': locale
        });
    }));
it('check report name', function(done) {
        var data = window.$json.$get('app/languages/en-US/home.lang.json');
        locale.ready('myreport')
            .then(function() {
                expect(scope.reportname).toBe("gauravreport");
                done();
            })
            .catch(done.fail);
    });
```

Issue is when I  run this test, it says reportname is not defined. It seems that its not able to resolve the locale service.

Comment: What is `locale.ready`? Please provide code for units where you use it and current tests where you are unable to mock it.

Comment: Attached the code which I want to unit test. Cannot post the entire code. I am not sure how to use it, so looking for any code samples.

Comment: The whole purpose of passing dependencies to $controller is to pass mocked dependencies. Passing real `locale` makes absolutely no sense. Pass a mock instead.

Comment: But how do I create a mock for locale?

Comment: Like you usually do in Jasmine, a new object with `jasmine.createSpyObj` or so. See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653702/return-a-promise-in-jasmine-directive-controller . If you don't know how to mock Angular services with Jasmine, I would suggest to ask a new question. All-in-one questions have less chances to get a proper answer.

Comment: I think you cannot mock service that returns a promise with createSpy..

Comment: Of course, you can. That's what the link from the previous comment shows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145364/discussion-between-gaurav-saini-and-estus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, using the approach stated here:

[Testing Promises with Jasmine - Provide and Spy](http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine_Provide_Spy/)